# where does STL vector keeps data items of varying size?

Tags: c++, stl

Specifically, how does STL align vector items in vector< vector< T > > , given that each of the vector items may change size? Does the outer vector aligns references and keeps the items elsewhere?

Comment: Items cannot change size. If they could, how would `sizeof(type)` work? A normal item's actual allocation size cannot change. If it could, you could not create a vector of such an item.

Answer (score 6):

A `std::vector` holds a pointer to the first element of array. When the number of elements change and the array needs to grow or shrink a new array is allocated and the data is copied. The actual size of the vector object itself never changes.

Comment: Also, the size of each object in the vector doesn't change. If you have `vector<T>` then `sizeof(T)` bytes are needed for each item in the vector.

Comment: What was wrong with the phrase 'pointer to an array'? Which element other than the first could that possibly point to?

Comment: @Roddy: A 'pointer to an array', and a 'pointer to the first element of that array' are different types.  When you increment a pointer to an array, it moves by the size of the whole array.  When you increment a pointer to the first element of an array, it moves to the second element of that array.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors typically don't "change size". In general, the storage of the vector is implemented using a pointer-to-`T` member variable. (And it's only the memory pointed to by that pointer that's reallocated upon resizing, and naturally, that doesn't change the size of the vector instance itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Standard vector is fundamentally a wrapper around this

```
template<typename T>
class vector
{
    T* m_data;
    size_t m_count;
    size_t m_capacity;

    //...
    void push_back(const T& src) {
        if (m_capacity < m_count + 1) {
            size_t newCapacity = m_capacity + growthRate();
            T* newData = ::realloc(m_data, newCapacity);
            // ...
            m_data = newData;
            m_capacity = newCapacity;
        }

        // copy into the slot at m_count
        m_data[m_count] = src;
        ++m_count;
    }
};
```

As such, a given instance of a vector always stores the same size of element. The only way it can contain polymorphic or variable items is via pointers, e.g.

```
class Base {};
class D1 : public Base {};
class D2 : public Base { int i; };

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vec;

vec.emplace_back(new Base);
vec.emplace_back(new D1);
vec.emplace_back(new D2);
```